# Find the name of the database I'm connected to in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to find out the name of the database I am connected to?

I have several includes to I don't know what is the db selected

Comment: Which database adapter are you using?

Comment: You either specify your database name or use it in your queries like this
Database.tablename You will probably find it in your connection file

Answer (score 1):

You can run a query to see which database you are connected to.

```
SELECT database() AS db;
```

See [`database()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_database).

Comment: That's assuming it's a mysql database. `current_database()` under postgres.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Thanks for clearing that up!